# $~\int\frac{1}{x+3}\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}\, dx~$with using the constraint $~t=\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}~$

Tags: integration

The only constraint to solve the below integral is to let$~t=\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}~$

$$L:=\int\frac{1}{x+3}\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}\, dx\tag{1}$$

**My try is as follows**

$$t=\sqrt{\frac{\left(x+2\right)}{\left(x+4\right)}}\tag{2}$$

$$\frac{dt}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}\right)\tag{3}$$

$$=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sqrt{x+2}\left(\sqrt{x+4}\right)^{-1}\right)\tag{4}$$

$$=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\left(x+2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\cdot\left(x+4\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)\tag{5}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+2}}\cdot\left(x+4\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}+\left(x+2\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(x+4\right)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\right)\tag{6}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+2}\sqrt{x+4}}-\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{2}\left(x+4\right)^{-\frac{3}{2}}\tag{7}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+2}\sqrt{x+4}}-\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{2}\frac{1}{\left(x+4\right)\sqrt{x+4}}\tag{8}$$

$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+4}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+2}}-\frac{\sqrt{x+2}}{x+4}\right)~~\leftarrow~~\text{Seems nothing can be done from here}\tag{9}$$

$$t=\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}~~\leftarrow~~\text{this constraint is too heavy for me}\tag{10}$$

I need your wisdom.

Comment: “Constraint” is an unusual term here. You seem to doing a substitution. Everything becomes a bit let noisy if you first substitute $u=x+3.$ But I don’t know where to go from there.

Comment: Use WolframAlpha you will see that the integral is to complex..

Comment: @AnAlien I did it already but wolfram showed the path for solution without using substitution of $t=\sqrt{\frac{x+2}{x+4}}$

Comment: You better express x in terms of t for changing dx to dt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, express $x$ in terms of $t$. Squaring, we get
$$t^2=\frac{x+2}{x+4}=1-\frac{2}{x+4}\\x+4=\frac{2}{1-t^2}
\\x=\frac{4t^2-2}{1-t^2}\\
\Rightarrow dx=\frac{4t}{(1-t^2)^2}dt$$
Then substitute in the integral:
$$\int\frac{t}{3+\frac{4t^2-2}{1-t^2}}\frac{4t}{(1-t^2)^2}\,dt=\int\frac{4t^2}{(1-t^2)(t^2+1)}\,dt$$
The partial fraction decomposition is
$$\begin{align}\frac{4t^2}{(1-t^2)(t^2+1)}&=
\frac{2(1+t^2)-2(1-t^2)}{(1-t^2)(t^2+1)}\\
&=\frac{2}{1-t^2}-\frac{2}{t^2+1}\\
&=\frac{1}{1-t}+\frac{1}{t+1}-\frac{2}{t^2+1}\end{align} $$
Can you continue from here?

Comment: I got$~\frac{\left(\sqrt{x+2}+\sqrt{x+4}\right)^{2}}{6}~$